# What kind of infraction is Mr. Morfin referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-terror

In [The Terror](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2708480/) (season 1, episode 4 ) there's a scene where Dr. Goodsir is treating Mr. Morfin for a headache. The doctor asks Morfin for what infraction he has been lashed in the past, to which he laughs and answers "what do you think, sir?".

The doctor looks away, awkwardly as if he can guess what Morfin meant, but what did he? What sort of infraction would be so obvious (at the time, to a seaman) that needed no explanation?

Comment: I think the implication was that it was for sodomy. But I don't know that it's ever fully explained.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I don't think it's explained, but I suspect it's implied in a subtle way that I just can't grasp.